# Assign a firebase database url(String) to a Database Reference variable?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to assign a string that contains a url for a place in my database to a DatabaseReference type.
Example:

```
String strRef = "my database url";
DatabaseReference ref = //here I want to assign the content of strRef.
```

Update (from comment to Alex's answer):

I'm getting from another activity a specific url that point on a place in my database.and now I need to cast it to a DatabaseReference type that I'll be able to read from this place in my database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you get a full URL to a location in the database from somewhere, you can create a `DatabaseReference` to that location with:

```
String url = "https://<your-project>.firebaseio.com/path/to/data";
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
```

So the above works if your URL starts with `https://<your-project>.firebaseio.com/`.

If you get a full path instead, you'd use:

```
String path = "/path/to/data";
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
```